# Can I check parent element has specific class in sass?

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I want to assign value conditionally if parent element has a specific class. Exp:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.child {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

but if parent element has a class named "big"

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent big">
    <div class="child">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

I want to change value as follows

**CSS**

```
.child {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

For example as follows:

```
.child {
  font-size: parent.hasClass('big') ? 20px : 16px;
}
```

How can I do that in SASS?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Simply create two rules:

```
.child {font-size: 16px;}
.big .child {font-size: 20px;}
```

---

In SASS it would be

```
.child
    font-size: 16px

    .big &
        font-size: 20px
```

Comment: This was really helpful, does anybody know what the use of the `&` in this case is called?

Comment: Parent selector. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector

Comment: Better to use `>` to only target its direct parent.

Comment: @AsefHossini There is no parent selector in CSS. Also `>` is direct child selector and that is no _better_ solution as it depends on situation

Comment: thanks, that's very useful, what about `.big.child` instead of `.big .child`

Comment: `.big&` - remove space between selectors

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible using pure CSS (the whole idea is cascading). But there might be a way using SASS. Check this out:

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand

EDIT: Another option would be using JavaScript, like Jpegzilla suggested.

Comment: Yeah, got you. What I was saying is that impossible to address the parent element using pure css.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed that

Answer (score -2):

There are no parent selectors in CSS. What you can do is setting your font-size on your parent class and let the children inherit that.

```
.parent {
    font-size: 16px;

    &.big {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

.child {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Or you can use CSS variables (if you don't need to worry about IE too much)

```
--font-size: 16px;

.big {
    --font-size: 20px;
}

.parent {
    font-size: var(--font-size);
}

.child {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: There **are** parent selectors in SASS (scss) though. That's what the OP questioned about.