# SCSS level parent

Tags: sass, less

I have code now:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="second select">
        <div class="third">
            <button>OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and SCSS code to him:

```
.parent{
    .second{
        .third{
            button{
                background: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add a select class to a button in SCSS without creating a separate type for it:

```
.parent{
    .second{
        .third{
            button{
                background: red;
            }
        }

        &.select{
            .third{
                button{
                    background: green;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for example, using mixins to find this item (maybe there is a ready-made solution out of the box)

```
.parent{
    .second{
        .third{
            button{
                background: red;

                @include find('.select',2){ // 2 or '.second' => 2 it's position (second) or search class ".second"
                    background: green;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
$colors: red, green, yellow, blue;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
 button:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
  background: nth($colors, $i);
 }
}

.wrapper {
  button {
    padding: 15px 65px;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
    <button>OK</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not need to use pseudo-elements, I need to know if the parent element has a certain class, then give it the desired style. I set the button as an example only. There can use div blocks

Comment: You wanted to give red on buttons but green only if there's any class .select? 
Check the code again. I have updated or let me know what exactly u want

Comment: I already have this code of two branches, starting with the class of the "second". I would like to know how to shorten the code using mixins, search the tree. Example above

Comment: Can you please check if that helps

Comment: Please check again :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. And studied at the same time SCSS :)

Mixin:

```
@mixin find($find, $new) {
    $newselector: ();

    @each $selector in & {
        $length: length($selector);

        @for $i from 1 through $length {
            $ff: nth($selector,$i);

            @if($ff == $find){
                $ff: $ff#{$new};
            }

            $newselector: append($newselector, $ff);
        }
    }

    @at-root #{$newselector} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

SCSS:

```
.parent{
    .second{
        .third{
            button{
                background: red;

                @include find('.second','.select'){
                    background: green;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only my opinion, but your solution is very difficult to read. It is better to keep your code simple: KISS > DRY. Moreover, in this case, you have a nested selector problem: http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule. So, if you remove some selector, this could be a good solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983769/can-i-check-parent-element-has-specific-class-in-sass. Cheers  ;)